# Using protofub for ASP.NET Web API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, protobuf-net

I am working on a bunch of Web APIs which must have a latency of a single digit millisecond! To produce the response I am using protobuf which is great. My question is that can protobuf be used to de-serialize the request as well?

For example for such an API:

```
public async Task<List<Artist>> Search(SearchArtistRequest request)
```

I will write a SDK (a bunch of .DLL) which will make the call to this API and third parties will only use the .DLL. So if I could send my request message in protobuf format and de-serialize 'request' using protobuf then I might gain some performance improvements (given that by default Json.NET is used and its performance is aweful). Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Just word of caution, if you use something fancy, like protobuf, for your top level API, you'd probably tie the technology stack to .NET and to your client-side .dll. If you have many customers all using different languages, e.g. Java, PHP or even perhaps JavaScript for Ajax calls - you'd greatly impact their ability to make requests, as they must serialise request data in a protobuf format (which is doable - but could be painful, e.g. dates and strings can be particularly difficult). Your goal sounds unrealistic anyway - you can just spend more time setting up TCP connection even before HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own serializer, test it and replace existing one with yours in WebAPI.

There are a couple of resources about custom serialization in WebAPI.
Look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#removing_the_json_or_xml_formatter) ("Testing Object Serialization"), [Media Formatters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) and [Replace...serializer](http://blog.developers.ba/replace-json-net-jil-json-serializer-asp-net-web-api/).